# if statement in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables on my database :

### Users :

```
id  ------- username
1            user1  
2            user2
```

### writers

```
id  ------- name
4           writer4
5           writer5 
8           writer8
```

### Following :

```
user_id  -----  follow  
1               5
1               8
2               5
```

so, now User1 follows writer5 and writer8 , and user2 follows writer5

I'm login to my app as user1 , when I go to the writers page I get list of all writers in the database ..
I just want to show in front of each writer whether I'm following this writer or not ..

List Writers Page example:

```
writer4     :follow
writer5     :unfollow (i'm following him now)
writer8     :unfollow (i'm following him now)
writer100     :follow
```

my question is : Is there a query to get the full list of writers and give me a value=0 if I'm not (as user1) following this writer

any ideas ?
thanks ..

Comment: you can use pl/sql for conditioning

Comment: any ideas how can I do that ? thanks ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `CROSS JOIN` in order for user to get all writers.

```
SELECT b.name,if(c.userid is null, 'follow', 'unfollow') result
FROM users a
        CROSS JOIN writers b
        LEFT JOIN following c
          on a.id = c.userid AND
             b.id = c.follows
WHERE a.id = 1
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d586/25)

Comment: @Ahmad your accepted answer doesn't return all the list of writers on your table but instead it will only show the writer for which the user has been following. [*see this link*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d586/13)

Comment: Totet , actually I got all list of writers on my table, and also get isFolloing = user_id .. so I check if isFollowing==logged_in_user , if so that means the logged_in_user follows this writer .. I'll check it again now to make sure , thanks a lot John ..

Comment: now I make an if condition statement inside my foreach loop to see if the logged_in_user follows the writer or not, what about ur code ?

Comment: did you see the sample on sqlfiddle? by using that, you will not use an `IF` statement in your php file.

Comment: ahaa yes, u are right I got it now, but in my case I have users table on another server so I just get the user_id from session , so I could not use ur code because there is no users table in my local database ,otherwise, yes it will work great, thanks a lot for ur help John, really appreciate that  :)

Comment: u were right , I came back to use ur code ;) cuz I just knew how to join 2 tables from 2 different databases .. thanks again ..

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT
 writers.username,
 IFNULL(following.user_id,0) AS isFollowing
FROM
 writers
 LEFT JOIN following ON writers.id = following.follow
```

Then in php you could check to see if `$results['isFollowing']` is true (>=1) or false (0) and display what you need.

Comment: Your solution is a little more elegant than mine, what with the boolean result and such :)

Comment: @Ahmad this will only return rows that a certain user is following. [*see this link*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d586/13) .

Comment: @Ahmad - at the sake of my "reputation", John is right - you'll want to use the cross join in his example.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you outer join following to writers on the key of your user ID:

```
select w.*, f.user_id from writers w
left outer join following f on f.follow = w.id 
and f.user_id = <INSERT USER ID HERE>
```

That should return a list of all writers, and will show your user ID for writers you follow, and null for writers you don't.  You'd then base your follow/unfollow logic on that.

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL supports programming language features like conditional statements, iterative statements.

The programming constructs are similar to how you use in programming languages like Java and C++. In this section I will provide you syntax of how to use conditional statements in PL/SQL programming.

```
IF condition 

THEN 

 statement 1; 

ELSE 

 statement 2; 

END IF;
```

[for further reference check this link](http://www.plsqltutorial.com/plsql-if-statement/)